# Direct proof divisibility: Suppose $x$ is an integer such that $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot x = 59 \cdot 58 \cdot 57 \cdot 56 \cdot 55$

Tags: divisibility

Suppose $\,x\,$ is an integer such that $\,2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot x = 59 \cdot 58 \cdot 57 \cdot 56 \cdot 55.\,$
Does $\,59 \mid x$?  Does $\,29 \mid x$? Does $\,118 \mid x$?

Comment: Are those meant to be products, $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot x = 59 \cdot 58 \cdot 57 \cdot 56 \cdot 55$?

Comment: i dont know, its the question given, but i would assume yes since the numbers are quite large

Answer (score 2):

59 is a prime number. Since the right hand side is divisible by 59, so must the left hand side. And 2, 3, 4, 5 don't provide a factor divisible by 59. So x must be divisible by 59.

The other parts to the question follow on similarly by noticing that $58 = 2 × 29$, $118 = 2 × 59$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$
\require{cancel}
\require{color}
%\let\oldcdot\cdot
\let\oldcancel\cancel
%\renewcommand{\cdot}{\!\oldcdot\!}
\renewcommand{\cancel}[1]{\!\color{blue}\oldcancel{\,\color{black}#1\,}}
$
The answer is **yes**, numbers $\,59,$ $\,29,$ and  $\,118\,$ all divide $\,x$.

From the equation $\,2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot x = 59 \cdot 58 \cdot 57 \cdot 56 \cdot 55.\,$ we conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= \dfrac{ 59 \cdot 58 \cdot 57 \cdot 56 \cdot 55}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5} 
= \dfrac{ 59 \cdot 
\left( 29\cdot \! \cancel{2} \right) \cdot 
\left( 19\cdot \! \cancel{3} \right) \cdot 
\left( 14\cdot \! \cancel{4} \right) \cdot 
\left( 11\cdot \! \cancel{5} \right) }
{\cancel{2} \cdot \cancel{3} \cdot \cancel{4} \cdot \cancel{5}} 
=\\
&= 59 \cdot 29 \cdot 19 \cdot 14 \cdot 11
= 59 \cdot 29 \cdot 19 \cdot \left(7\cdot2\right) \cdot 11 
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus we have 
$$
\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{ x = 59 \cdot 29 \cdot 19 \cdot 11 \cdot 7 \cdot 2}
$$
Since $\,118 =  59\cdot2,\,$ we see right away that $\,59 \mid x,\,$  $\,29 \mid x,\,$  and $\,118 \mid x.\,$

Comment: @snulty You are right, thank you for pointing out my typo.

Comment: No problem, I'll delete the earlier comment now